# A strange mutable reference created in a method call affects the use of the variable outside

Tags: rust

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Data<'a> {
    i: &'a [i32],
    start: i32,
}

impl<'a> Data<'a> {
    fn new<const I: usize>(arr: &[i32; I]) -> Data {
        Data { i: arr, start: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Data<'a> {
    type Item = & 'a i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if (self.start as usize) < self.i.len(){
           let r = &self.i[self.start as usize];
           self.start+=1;
           Some(r)
        }else{
           None
        }
        //todo!()
    }
}

struct WrapperData<'a> {
    v: &'a Data<'a>,
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut WrapperData<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    type IntoIter = Data<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        *self.v
    }
}

fn main(){
    let arr = [1, 2, 3];
    let d = Data{start:0,i:&arr};
    let mut wr = WrapperData { v: &d };
    let ddd = wr.into_iter(); // #1
    let r = wr.v;  // #2 error
}
```

`#1` does create a mutable borrowing from `wr` for the invocation of `into_iter`, however, after the invocation of the function, the implicitly created mutably borrowing is not used anymore, why the compiler still say `#2` is an error with the diagnosis

```
69 |     let r = wr.v;
   |             ^^^^
   |             |
   |             use of borrowed `wr`
   |             borrow later used here
```

Cannot figure out the reason here.

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented `IntoIterator` for `&'a WrapperData<'a>`, so you're telling the compiler that the lifetime of the borrow is the same as the lifetime of the wrapper. So when you call `wr.into_iter()` the compiler borrow `wr` for its whole lifetime, even if the result of `into_iter` is later dropped. You want to use different lifetimes here:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Data<'a> {
    i: &'a [i32],
    start: i32,
}

impl<'a> Data<'a> {
    fn new<const I: usize>(arr: &[i32; I]) -> Data {
        Data { i: arr, start: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Data<'a> {
    type Item = & 'a i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if (self.start as usize) < self.i.len(){
           let r = &self.i[self.start as usize];
           self.start+=1;
           Some(r)
        }else{
           None
        }
        //todo!()
    }
}

struct WrapperData<'a> {
    v: &'a Data<'a>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> IntoIterator for &'b mut WrapperData<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    type IntoIter = Data<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        *self.v
    }
}

fn main(){
    let arr = [1, 2, 3];
    let d = Data{start:0,i:&arr};
    let mut wr = WrapperData { v: &d };
    let _ddd = wr.into_iter(); // #1
    let _r = wr.v;  // #2 error
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=95976dfcd3239db822f089a9ca6e26dc)

Comment: It's confusing, doesn't the book of rust explicitly says that: *Lifetime annotations don’t change how long any of the references live*? The tag `'a` here just validate whether the reference borrowing can occur at the call of `into_iter`, I think. Moreover, the implicitly created mutably borrowing at best is useful before the end of `wr.into_iter()`. I don't understand the key of giving a new `lifetime annotation` can resolve the issue.

Comment: This sentence in the book means that annotations don't change when a variable is dropped, but the compiler uses them to know when it is dropped. When calling a function the compiler doesn't look inside to know the lifetime relationships between the references involved but it relies on the annotations, and here that says: "_something inside that function requires the lifetime of the reference to be the same as the wrapper_". This is not true, the reference can have a shorter lifetime but the compiler can't know that. Adding a 2nd annotation tells the compiler that they are unrelated.